# How do I create an infinite loop of binary digits?

Tags: python, list, loops, binary

So for example:
0
10
11
100
101
110
111

And so on.

I would like to have it go infinitely, but that might not be possible.
I have already tried this:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
listres = [str(bin(x))[2:].zfill(4) for x in lista]
print(listres)
```

And it works, but it is all one line, and also not infinite.

Comment: Since you need infinite items, you can not store those in list. Do you need your programs to infinitely just print the binary numbers ?

Comment: Use a generator function.

Comment: `while True: digit = random.choice([0,1])`

Answer (score 3):

You could create a generator:

```
def infinite_binary():
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield str(bin(x))[2:]
        x += 1

infinite_binary_gen = infinite_binary()
while True:
    print(next(infinite_binary_gen))
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
1000
1001
... and so on
```

---

As mentioned in [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s comment you can use [`itertools.count(start=0, step=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for the base generator:

```
from itertools import count

infinite_binary_gen = (str(bin(x))[2:] for x in count())
while True:
    print(next(infinite_binary_gen))
```

Comment: More simply, `itertools.count` already provides the base generator needed. `infinite_binary_gen = (str(bin(x))[2:] for x in count())`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a while loop. This way, you could do it in 4 lines of code. Try this:

```python
count = 1

while True:
    listres = str(bin(count))[2:].zfill(4)
    print(listres)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop like this instead of a list comprehension:

```
i = 0
while True:
    # uncomment this line to break the infinite loop:
    # if i > 10: break
    print(str(bin(i))[2:])
    i += 1
```

Note that `zfill(4)` is not needed here.

If you need to cast the result to
`int`, use: `print(int(str(bin(i))[2:]))`